# Display a page on website located on different server

Tags: php, iis, dns

I have a php website running on an IIS8 server. I also have a WordPress blog hosted on another server. I would like for the blog to show up under the same domain as the main site.

For example, www.mysite.com is hosted on server A. The blog is hosted on server B. The domain name is set to server A. When a user navigates to www.mysite.com they get the main website hosted on server A. When the user navigates to www.mysite.com/posts, I need them to see the blog hosted on server B. Is this possible? I'm not sure if I can use a cname, if I need to configure something in IIS or if there is another way to accomplish this.

Comment: You could just keep things simple and use an iframe?

Comment: How would an iframe help if the domain is pointed at server A? Right now, www.mysite.com/posts just gives a 404 error because, technically, there is nothing located at that URL. The blog is hosted on another server but I need to be able to use the same domain name.

Comment: Create a page in posts.html and embed an iframe in it. Then put some rewrite rules on the IIS server to make it "/posts". Does that solves your issue?

Comment: Or even just a folder called "posts" with "index.html" inside it - messier on the backend but maybe faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you describe it, www.mysite.com/blog might not be the easiest or cleanest solution. If you are able to, using a sub-domain would be better.

The blog would end up at `blog.mysite.com` or whatever you want. Site A would still be at `www.mysite.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can see there being several options here. The iframe suggestion I don't think quite fits your requirement of typing a URL and then it redirecting.

You could add a simple domain redirect for example mysite.com/posts redirects too Server B. You could look at using rewirte URL's on IIS. See the URL rewrite extension [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply call an API from server B that will fetch blog data and return the output

Create an API function on Server A that returns the blog post data (in array/object format)